# Can I use Google/Yahoo Maps API to lookup cities/states based on the zip?

Tags: google-maps, google-api, yahoo-api

I came across this when I did a search on SO:
[Zip Code to City/State and vice-versa in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518026/zip-code-to-city-state-and-vice-versa-in-a-database)

But I'm wondering, why can't we just use the Maps APIs for this? Has anyone tried doing this?

Answer (score 1):

use the google maps api [Geocoder](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's pretty easy to do it with Google Maps Geocoding [getLocations()](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GClientGeocoder.getLocations).

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Geocoding example</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   var geocoder;
   var map;
   var address = "10001"; //NEW YORK zip
   function load()
   {
      map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
      geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
      geocoder.getLocations(address, addToMap);
   }
   function addToMap(response)
   {
      place = response.Placemark[0];
      point = new GLatLng(place.Point.coordinates[1],place.Point.coordinates[0]);
      map.setCenter(point, 13);
      marker = new GMarker(point);
      map.addOverlay(marker);
      marker.openInfoWindowHtml(place.address);
   }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You could give it a try online on Google code [playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=maps#geocoding_extraction).
Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to use the [Geonames](http://geonames.org) webservice apis for this, specifically [the postalCodeSearch](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html) method.  Works great in my experience unless you're issuing multiple queries/second, although caching results is generally worthwhile. (ie: they do not change frequently.)