# Best Practice For Storing ZIP Code Information

Tags: database

I'm trying to design a precise database following the normal standards of database design taught, and I'm stuck on the idea of a ZIP Code table. I've put a table together for zip code information with the following specs:

```
-PK | zip_code_id | NN UQ - BIGINT
-   | zip_code    | NN - STRING(5)
-   | city        | NN - STRING(40)
-   | state       | NN - STRING(2)
```

however I'm stuck if I should include the ZIP+4 in the table or as a field for whatever record I use. My question is this: According to best practices should the ZIP+4 be included in the separate table used for zip codes or should that be used in as a field in whatever record this table is used with? This will only be using american addresses.

I'm open to any redesign if my design is to restrictive ie allowing non-american addresses.

Comment: Will this database store international postal codes as well, or just US zip codes?

Comment: @Prix i'm pretty sure a zip code can cover more than 1 city. so  making the zip code the pk is not an option.

Comment: The next few years or so, it will store US only zip codes. Then that changes. Or the zip pattern itself changes (happened in Germany). The more restrictive you design it now, the more someone will hate you in the future.

Comment: ZIP codes can cover more than one city, and a city can have more than one ZIP code. Some ZIP codes even span states.

Comment: Also there's no reason to reinvent the wheel. There are free web services that do lookups. Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518026/zip-code-to-city-state-and-vice-versa-in-a-database) seems somewhat relevant.

Comment: if someone want to know how write address of whatever country this is useful link http://www.columbia.edu/~fdc/postal/#index